# Ruby on Rails -- Using multiple has_many associations to the same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a simple program where an event can be created by a user, and the Event class knows who created it:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base

  # the owner of the event
  belongs_to :user

end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  # a user has 0 to n created events
  has_many :events

end
```

So far so good, I get the correct association behaviour when I call "event.user" for example, and only the creator of the event can perform CRUD operations on his/her event.

However I want the ability for a user to save events (not in the database sense, just so they can view it in their dashboard or such), and I want to just use these two models. I tried adding a "user_saved_id" to the Event model as a new column to keep track of the users which save it like the following:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base

  # the owner of the event
  belongs_to :user

end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  # a user has 0 to n created events
  has_many :events

  # a user has 0 to n saved events, including the created event
  has_many :saved_events, foreign_key: 'user_saved_id', class_name: "Event"

end
```

However I am having no such luck. When I try to initialize an event creator to have automatically saved his/her own event when he/she creates it for example, I get an " undefined method `each' " in the create method below (I am using the devise gem, and "current_user" is a helper function which returns the id of the current signed in user):

```
# POST /events
# POST /events.json
  def create
    @event = Event.new(event_params)

    # associate an event with its creator, works correctly
    @event.user = current_user

    # initialize a user to have saved his own events, not working
    @event.user.saved_events = current_user
 ...
```

I would greatly appreciate any pointers I can get on where I am getting it wrong, if I got the association relationship wrong, and if I am overthinking it and there is a simpler way to go about it. Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: I'm a little confused on the "saved events" part.  Aren't these events already saved in the db?  Could you explain that a little more?

Comment: Of course, a user can "save events", such that they can see it in their dashboard to view later, I don't mean save in the db sense.

Comment: Ah. I'll update my answer. Best to clarify that in your question, if you will.

Comment: Also, your question title is very misleading. Please update for posterity's sake.

Comment: Ah my apologies, I've edited it. Really appreciate you taking the time to write your answer, I will give it a shot and let you know if it works. Thanks very much.

Comment: Can more than 1 user save an event for their dashboard? Or are events only seen/saved by and individual user?

Comment: Oh let me clear that up: the intention was that an event can be "saved" by any user, so initially it will be saved by the creator, then other users can "save" the same event if they wish. There are many events, each of which has a creator, and each event can be "saved" for viewing at a later time (so this would be like clicking the "I am going" button in facebook).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with adding the user to the event as `user_saved_id`, is that only 1 user will ever be able to save that event.   If I understand correctly, you would like a user to be able save events (That they may or may not have created?) to be shown in their Dashboard.  In this case you are going to need something like a `has_and_belongs_to_many` or a `has_many through` type relationship, and thus another table. Perhaps something like using the has_many through.

```
class SavedEvent < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :event 
end 

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

 # a user has 0 to n created events
  has_many :events
  has_many :saved_events

  # a user has 0 to n saved events through the favorites table
  has_many :later_events,  through: :saved_events 
 end
```

when you create your `SavedEvent`, you can use the created_at timestamp to show when the user saved it, or can also store other information/metadata about saving it.

having the reverse set it event would allow you easily get the list of users who have saved this Event via `event.saved_users`.  (sorry naming things is one of those hard problems)

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base

  # the owner of the event
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :saved_events
  has_many :saved_users, through: :saved_events 

end
```

then creating a new event would be

```
def create
  #wrap in transaction 
  Event.transaction do
   #build the event through the association  
   @event = current_user.events.create!(event_params)
   #save it to the current users saved events
   current_user.saved_events.create!(event: @event)
  end 
 end
```

the transaction and the ! methods just make it so that it will roll back if it cannot create the event and add to saved events, and not wind up with an event that isn't in the saved/later events table when created.

When another user wants to save the event, in your controller for that, you just need to do `current_user.saved_events.create(event: event)` for them, and it will save it.

Then in your dashboard you can do `current_user.later_events` and get a collection of all events that they have saved.

Comment: Thanks so much, really appreciate your time explaining your code. It works wonderfully, but just wanted to ask if I wanted to delete a particular saved event, is it just current_user.saved_events.destroy? Doesn't seem to be working, but I will look into it more, thanks.

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out: @event = Event.find(params[:event]), followed by: current_user.saved_events.find(@event).destroy works. Apologies I dont know how to add code markdown in comments. Thanks again.

Comment: Was going to say you should should just need to find the saved_event by event id and then destroy that specific saved_event. current_user.saved_events.find_by_event_id(@event.id). Also found a typo on the reverse side  event Should have many shared_events not belong to. Will update answer

Comment: Hmm you are correct, but it seems to behave correctly even with the typo, maybe I haven't used a command yet that will cause it to fail though but will update my db. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a `User` to be given the ability to "save" an event (in the sense of a dashboard, not a database), why not add a `save_for_later` flag to `Event`?

`rails g migration add_save_for_later_to_events save_for_later:boolean`

Then in your `Event` model, you can add the following scope:

```
scope :flagged_events_for, (lambda do |user|
    where('user_id = ? AND save_for_later = ?', user.id, true)
  end)
```

You'll then be able to "ask" the `Event` model for appropriate instances of itself elsewhere in your app, with `Event.flagged_events_for(user)`